# ImageView.contentMode doesn't work on collection view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view. I placed a ImageView on each cell of the collection view. Then I set the contentMode of the image view to be ScaleAspectFit but it doesn't have any impact. Is there any problem on using contentMode inside a collection view? Below is the code I am using.

```
class PictureCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var coverImg: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var pic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var clickPicBtn: UIButton!

var row:Int = 0

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.pic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
}
```

Comment: What's your expected effect? How does it look instead? You need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a storyboard to add the collection view or is it done programmatically?  I have one added with a storyboard, and I changed the aspect ration of the image view placed in the collection view from there.

I am populating the images similar to a tableview, using repeating cells and an array of images.  Having the content view mode of the image view, not the collection view, works in my case.

Comment: I am using storyboard for collection view and a xib for the UICollectionViewCell. How did you change the aspect ration of the image view?

Comment: @ZhaoYi in the attributes inspector for the image view which I am populating with an image, I set the aspect ratio to aspect fit.  There is a drop down choice.  I am not populating the cell per se, but populating an image view I placed in the cell.

Comment: Yes, I did the same but it doesn't have any impact on the image view.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to set constraints on the imageView.

Following code works for me:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    print("init cell")
}

func setupCell(){
    self.label.text = "hello world!"
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Fat_Cat")
    self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
}
```

}

Comment: where is the constraints you set?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Eaziest is to set them in storyboard